# VB Code to get Dashboard to refresh without locking other speadsheet for editing to get other spreadsheet information at a set time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a dashboard in Excel that watches a different excel spreadsheet we use for data entry. It's important that I avoid locking the spreadsheet out for editing, I first tried using the workbook connections however it locks the spreadsheet so it can't be edited it is even set up a shared one drive, I have tried changing the timer to 5 minutes value but this makes no difference. I have seen on forums that a person had a similar issue but used VB and wrote coding.
I have lots of experience using excel but none using VB I don't know where to start.

what I need help with is a simple code creating to get my dashboard pivot tables to refresh at whatever time in minutes then it will talk to my other spreadsheet.

the code I have managed to write as a novice is:

```
Public Sub Refresh()
'refresh
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:30") 'hh:mm:ss
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Refresh"

End Sub
```

but this locks the main spreadsheet for any editing after imputing the VBA code in the module area 
I made sure I saved the excel spreadsheet as a macro and changed the options to allow macros

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please remember to **always** post your code in indented blocks.  If you need help doing this, you can look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90407/easy-way-to-indent-code) for an explanation.

Comment: Are you sure this is vb.net? Maybe it is VBA?

Comment: If it is locking, perhaps after the 'refresh' line, throw in `Sheet1.Unprotect`. Since you're not explicitly locking it, perhaps Excel is doing it for a reason, and that you can use the above line to unlock when the refresh is complete. Yes, your text implies VB.net and not VBA. Hopefully help, though...